# Installing docker to unsupported OS

Tags: windows, docker, installation, docker-toolbox

I want to install Docker Desktop to my computer. My operating system is Windows 10 Enterprise 14393.0. But version 18363+ is needed to install docker. I googled the issue and most of recommendations were to install docker toolbox. However, Toolbox is not available right now. In this case is it possible to install docker to my computer? If yes, how can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can continue to use Docker Toolbox, you can find the binary here: https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases

It will use an old version of docker and it's really not perfect, but if you can't update your Windows, it's the only way to have a not so old Docker.

The Docker Community Edition 2.0.0.3 have Docker 18.09 and the last Toolbox version have Docker 19.03.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install Docker Community Edition 2.0.0.3 which you can find [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/#docker-community-edition-2003-2019-02-15).